# Windows 8 upgrade space issue

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8-upgrade

I had 25 GB of free space. I tried to install windows 8 and it went till setting of files and settings and then it crashed. Now I only have 10 GB of free space and when I run the installer, it says to free up at least 20 GB. I do not understand where my space went.

I checked under `%localappdata%\Microsoft\WebSetup\`. It only stored the installation files and deleting it freed only 4 GB.

Answer (score 1):

So do you have a Windows installed at the moment? If so go to

Click on the Start button and then choose Control Panel.

Click on the System and Security link.

In the System and Security window, click on the Administrative Tools heading located near the bottom of the window.

In the Administrative Tools window, double-click on the Computer Management icon.

When Computer Management opens, click on Disk Management on the left side of the window, located under Storage.

There you can see all your spaces. Maybe it helps.